Pyhon post_init with changed static defaule attribute
Hey i was wondering about next behaviour
If we have lets say dataclass with None values by default and we want to re-set a value for future instances of this class, the current behaiour of __post_init__ does not take to the account changed static value and pass to the signature loaded first in memory described values of the class.
@dataclass
class A:
    attr1: str = None
    attr2: str = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        if not A.attr2:
            self.attr2 = '1234'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.attr1} - {self.attr2}'


A.attr2 = 'qwe'
a = A(attr1='oneoneone')
print(a)


At first I expected that all instances of A would have
attr2 = 'qwe'

But it does not, because it loaded with None being passed to __post_init__.
oneoneone - None

If we change default value of attr2 to
@dataclass
class A:
    attr1: str = None
    attr2: str = 'QWERTY'

We see the initializer works
oneoneone - QWERTY


This isn't a __post_init__ thing. A.attr2 = 'qwe' doesn't change the default value. That's fixed when the dataclass decorator runs.

Why it does not, if I see it does in variables during debug?
Or - how to achieve the changed value? Because since dataclass is not frozen, i thought i can do that

@dataclass does this (in pseudocode):
def __dataclasses_A__init__(self, attr1 = None, attr2 = None):
    self.attr1 = attr1
    self.attr2 = attr2
A.__init__ = __dataclasses_A__init__

Even if you modify the attribute later, the function that was generated by dataclass() function is already set in stone and has default values and will not change. You might be interested in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/dataclasses.py#L646 .


Can i change the value to achieve changed value in post_init?

I would do;
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Optional

default_attr2 = None

@dataclass
class A:
    attr1: Optional[str] = None
    attr2: Optional[str] = field(default_factory=lambda: default_attr2)

default_attr2 = 'qwe'
a = A(attr1='oneoneone')
print(a)


Thanks for source, will cap it. Exactly what i see in debug, yes. Signature has firstly loaded values. Can i change the value to achieve changed value in post_init?

Oh i see, it was generated...
